# Run Java file Service Mac

Tags: java, terminal, applescript, automator

So far i've created a service using automator to compile a Java file. This means that i can compile a java file through its contextual menu.

Unfortunately I cannot do the same with running the Java file. Through automator I can get it to run the java file perfectly, showing the results in the automator window, however it will not open the Terminal window to view the java file. I did this using this code:

```
java -classpath `dirname "$1"` `basename "$1" | sed "s/.class//g"`
```

Applescript on the other hand can run Terminal commands into a Terminal window for all to see using code such as:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script with command "java -classpath" & input & input
    end tell
end run
```

The correct way to run a java file is:

```
java -classpath /path/to/ file
```

Can anybody please help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Utilities > Run Shell Script` with `Passing input: as arguments` seems to work in this context.

Addendum: If you want to open Terminal, something like this may work.

```
open -a Terminal ~/your/script.sh
```